# XamlReader.Parse throws the "Invalid character in the given encoding"

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have a problem with the following code:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    ParserContext context = new ParserContext()
    {
        BaseUri = new Uri(Configuration.SkinsFolder)
        //,XmlLang = "utf-8" // I have tried with this parameter and without it
    };
    var result = XamlReader.Parse(content, context);
    return result;
}
```

The corresponding xaml, where problem appears:

```
...
<TextBlock>русская надпись</TextBlock>
<TextBlock Text="קח מספר" />
...
```

During parsing this xaml i get the exception:

```
Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 76, position 167.
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReaderHelper.RethrowAsParseException(String keyString, Int32 lineNumber, Int32 linePosition, Exception innerException)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReaderHelper.Read(XamlNode& xamlNode)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlParser.ReadXaml(Boolean singleRecordMode)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlParser._Parse()
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlParser.Parse()
```

Xaml file saved as utf-8

Anybody knows how i can load this xaml without such problems?
Thanks in advance!

PS: OK, i have found the source of the problem.

The correct way to load xaml is to use the XamlReader.Load method instead of the XamlReader.Parse. In my case it seems as:

```
using (Stream stream = new FileStream(source, FileMode.Open))
{
    ParserContext context = new ParserContext()
    {
        BaseUri = new Uri(Configuration.SkinsFolder)
    };
    var result = XamlReader.Load(stream, context);
    return result;
}
```

Thanks to all!

Comment: Are you sure it is UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: Yes, I have tried save this file as utf-8 with BOM, and without it too. In the both cases i have got the same result.

Comment: And when i show the read string throught VS watcher, it has not any troubles. All characters are correct.

Comment: I think the problem here is not the encoding, but the XamlParser. If you're giving it a string, already read in from the file, using the right encoding, then basically the XamlParser must disallow those characters in those places. I don't think this is encoding, this is validation. It might be that you're not allowed to use that kind of characters right there, or it might be a bug in the class. I assume you have verified the string after the `.ReadToEnd` and checked that it actually contains the right characters at that point, and isn't mangled?

Comment: Yes, string after .ReadToEnd is correct. Perhaps problem is in current culture? When i run this code on machine with Hebrew culture, i got message for the second string, but first string (russian characters) shows as question marks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had the same problem with German umlaut characters. I think there's a bug in the .NET Framework. Try to use this function instead of XamlReader.Parse(content, context):

```
public static object Parse(string xamlText, ParserContext parserContext)
{
  return System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load((Stream) new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xamlText)), parserContext);
}
```